# When is the trace of a matrix group surjective over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, trace

Let $p$ be a prime and $G\subset\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be a subgroup. I wondering about the following question:

Is the map $\operatorname{Tr}:G\to\mathbb{F}_p$ surjective?

I know it's true for $G=\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ with $n>1$.
Is it also true for $O_n(q,\mathbb{F}_p)$ where $q$ is a non-degenerate quadratic form over $\mathbb{F}_p$? Is it true for every finite group of Lie type if $p$ is large enough?

Comment: Note that your statement about $\mathrm{SL}_n$ is not true for $n=1$. This is a counterexample to your current statement, but perhaps it should be ruled out as "trivial" in some way

Comment: Thanks, I should correct it.